# How do I make the dateTimePicker not focused when the windows from app opens up?

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

I have created a windows form app. I want the focus to be in the Business Name textbox. However, when the form opens up, the focus is on the Date Discovered, specifically on 'October'. How do I change the focus to be on Business Name instead of Date Discovered?

Thanks!

```
        this.panBusinessInfo = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
        this.tbxEmail = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.lblEmail = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.tbxPhone = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.lblPhone = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.tbxContactPerson = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.lblContactPerson = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.tbxWayBackMachURL = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.tbxBusinessURL = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.tbxZipCode = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.cbxState = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
        this.tbxCity = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.tbxSuite = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.cbxIndustry = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
        this.tbxAddress = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.tbxBusinessName = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.lblIndustry = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.lblWayBackMachURL = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.lblBusinessURL = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.lblZipCode = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.lblState = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.lblCity = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.lblSuite = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.lblAddress = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.lblBusinessName = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.pnDates = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
        this.dtpProjFinish = new System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker();
        this.dtpProjStart = new System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker();
        this.dtpDateDisc = new System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker();
        this.lblProjFinishDate = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.lblProjStartDate = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.lblDateDiscovered = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.pnTerms = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
        this.btnCalculate = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.lblTMCost = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.lblTotMaint = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.lblSBCost = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.lblSiteBuildCost = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.chbxMaintOnly = new System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox();
        this.chbxBuildOut = new System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox();
        this.lblMaintOnly = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.lblMaintenacneFeeOnly = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.lblGTotal = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.lblGrandTotal = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.lblMonthlyPaymentCalc = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.lblMonthlyPayment = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.tbxNumMonths = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.lblNumMonths = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.tbxMaintFee = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.lblMaintenanceFee = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.tbxSBCost = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.lblTotContract = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.chbxPayments = new System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox();
        this.chbxFull = new System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox();
        this.lblTerms = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.pnNotes = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
        this.tbxNotes = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.lblNotesReq = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.pnButtons = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
        this.btnEmail = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.btnCreatePDF = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.btnSave = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.btnClear = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.btnClose = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.panBusinessInfo.SuspendLayout();
        this.pnDates.SuspendLayout();
        this.pnTerms.SuspendLayout();
        this.pnNotes.SuspendLayout();
        this.pnButtons.SuspendLayout();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // panBusinessInfo
        // 
        this.panBusinessInfo.Controls.Add(this.tbxEmail);
        this.panBusinessInfo.Controls.Add(this.lblEmail);
        this.panBusinessInfo.Controls.Add(this.tbxPhone);
        this.panBusinessInfo.Controls.Add(this.lblPhone);
        this.panBusinessInfo.Controls.Add(this.tbxContactPerson);
        this.panBusinessInfo.Controls.Add(this.lblContactPerson);
        this.panBusinessInfo.Controls.Add(this.tbxWayBackMachURL);
        this.panBusinessInfo.Controls.Add(this.tbxBusinessURL);
        this.panBusinessInfo.Controls.Add(this.tbxZipCode);
        this.panBusinessInfo.Controls.Add(this.cbxState);
        this.panBusinessInfo.Controls.Add(this.tbxCity);
        this.panBusinessInfo.Controls.Add(this.tbxSuite);
        this.panBusinessInfo.Controls.Add(this.cbxIndustry);
        this.panBusinessInfo.Controls.Add(this.tbxAddress);
        this.panBusinessInfo.Controls.Add(this.tbxBusinessName);
        this.panBusinessInfo.Controls.Add(this.lblIndustry);
        this.panBusinessInfo.Controls.Add(this.lblWayBackMachURL);
        this.panBusinessInfo.Controls.Add(this.lblBusinessURL);
        this.panBusinessInfo.Controls.Add(this.lblZipCode);
        this.panBusinessInfo.Controls.Add(this.lblState);
        this.panBusinessInfo.Controls.Add(this.lblCity);
        this.panBusinessInfo.Controls.Add(this.lblSuite);
        this.panBusinessInfo.Controls.Add(this.lblAddress);
        this.panBusinessInfo.Controls.Add(this.lblBusinessName);
        this.panBusinessInfo.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(8, 8);
        this.panBusinessInfo.Name = "panBusinessInfo";
        this.panBusinessInfo.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(305, 286);
        this.panBusinessInfo.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // tbxEmail
        // 
        this.tbxEmail.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(150, 135);
        this.tbxEmail.Name = "tbxEmail";
        this.tbxEmail.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(148, 20);
        this.tbxEmail.TabIndex = 9;
        // 
        // lblEmail
        // 
        this.lblEmail.AutoSize = true;
        this.lblEmail.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(150, 119);
        this.lblEmail.Name = "lblEmail";
        this.lblEmail.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(35, 13);
        this.lblEmail.TabIndex = 999;
        this.lblEmail.Text = "Email:";
        // 
        // tbxPhone
        // 
        this.tbxPhone.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(6, 135);
        this.tbxPhone.Name = "tbxPhone";
        this.tbxPhone.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(138, 20);
        this.tbxPhone.TabIndex = 8;
        // 
        // lblPhone
        // 
        this.lblPhone.AutoSize = true;
        this.lblPhone.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 119);
        this.lblPhone.Name = "lblPhone";
        this.lblPhone.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(41, 13);
        this.lblPhone.TabIndex = 999;
        this.lblPhone.Text = "Phone:";
        // 
        // tbxContactPerson
        // 
        this.tbxContactPerson.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(6, 250);
        this.tbxContactPerson.Name = "tbxContactPerson";
        this.tbxContactPerson.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(292, 20);
        this.tbxContactPerson.TabIndex = 12;
        // 
        // lblContactPerson
        // 
        this.lblContactPerson.AutoSize = true;
        this.lblContactPerson.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 234);
        this.lblContactPerson.Name = "lblContactPerson";
        this.lblContactPerson.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(83, 13);
        this.lblContactPerson.TabIndex = 999;
        this.lblContactPerson.Text = "Contact Person:";
        // 
        // tbxWayBackMachURL
        // 
        this.tbxWayBackMachURL.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(6, 212);
        this.tbxWayBackMachURL.Name = "tbxWayBackMachURL";
        this.tbxWayBackMachURL.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(292, 20);
        this.tbxWayBackMachURL.TabIndex = 11;
        // 
        // tbxBusinessURL
        // 
        this.tbxBusinessURL.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(6, 173);
        this.tbxBusinessURL.Name = "tbxBusinessURL";
        this.tbxBusinessURL.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(292, 20);
        this.tbxBusinessURL.TabIndex = 10;
        // 
        // tbxZipCode
        // 
        this.tbxZipCode.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(214, 97);
        this.tbxZipCode.Name = "tbxZipCode";
        this.tbxZipCode.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(84, 20);
        this.tbxZipCode.TabIndex = 7;
        // 
        // cbxState
        // 
        this.cbxState.FormattingEnabled = true;
        this.cbxState.Items.AddRange(new object[] {
        "AL",
        "AK",
        "AZ",
        "AR",
        "CA",
        "CO",
        "CT",
        "DE",
        "FL",
        "GA",
        "HI",
        "ID",
        "IL",
        "IN",
        "IA",
        "KS",
        "KY",
        "LA",
        "ME",
        "MD",
        "MA",
        "MI",
        "MN",
        "MS",
        "MO",
        "MT",
        "NE",
        "NV",
        "NH",
        "NJ",
        "NM",
        "NY",
        "NC",
        "ND",
        "OH",
        "OK",
        "OR",
        "PA",
        "RI",
        "SC",
        "SD",
        "TN",
        "TX",
        "UT",
        "VT",
        "VA",
        "WA",
        "WV",
        "WI",
        "WY"});
        this.cbxState.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(150, 97);
        this.cbxState.Name = "cbxState";
        this.cbxState.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(57, 21);
        this.cbxState.TabIndex = 6;
        // 
        // tbxCity
        // 
        this.tbxCity.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(6, 97);
        this.tbxCity.Name = "tbxCity";
        this.tbxCity.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(138, 20);
        this.tbxCity.TabIndex = 5;
        // 
        // tbxSuite
        // 
        this.tbxSuite.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(150, 59);
        this.tbxSuite.Name = "tbxSuite";
        this.tbxSuite.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
        this.tbxSuite.TabIndex = 4;
        // 
        // cbxIndustry
        // 
        this.cbxIndustry.FormattingEnabled = true;
        this.cbxIndustry.Items.AddRange(new object[] {
        "Alteration Shop",
        "Art Gallery",
        "Retail-Clothes/Shoes",
        "Retail-Hair and Beauty",
        "Retail-Other",
        "Services-Dry Cleaning",
        "Services-Food",
        "Services-Other",
        "Other"});
        this.cbxIndustry.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(150, 19);
        this.cbxIndustry.Name = "cbxIndustry";
        this.cbxIndustry.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(121, 21);
        this.cbxIndustry.TabIndex = 2;
        // 
        // tbxAddress
        // 
        this.tbxAddress.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(6, 59);
        this.tbxAddress.Name = "tbxAddress";
        this.tbxAddress.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(138, 20);
        this.tbxAddress.TabIndex = 3;
        // 
        // tbxBusinessName
        // 
        this.tbxBusinessName.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(6, 19);
        this.tbxBusinessName.Name = "tbxBusinessName";
        this.tbxBusinessName.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(138, 20);
        this.tbxBusinessName.TabIndex = 1;
        // 
        // lblIndustry
        // 
        this.lblIndustry.AutoSize = true;
        this.lblIndustry.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(147, 3);
        this.lblIndustry.Name = "lblIndustry";
        this.lblIndustry.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(47, 13);
        this.lblIndustry.TabIndex = 999;
        this.lblIndustry.Text = "Industry:";
        // 
        // lblWayBackMachURL
        // 
        this.lblWayBackMachURL.AutoSize = true;
        this.lblWayBackMachURL.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 195);
        this.lblWayBackMachURL.Name = "lblWayBackMachURL";
        this.lblWayBackMachURL.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(126, 13);
        this.lblWayBackMachURL.TabIndex = 999;
        this.lblWayBackMachURL.Text = "WayBack Machine URL:";
        // 
        // lblBusinessURL
        // 
        this.lblBusinessURL.AutoSize = true;
        this.lblBusinessURL.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 157);
        this.lblBusinessURL.Name = "lblBusinessURL";
        this.lblBusinessURL.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(77, 13);
        this.lblBusinessURL.TabIndex = 999;
        this.lblBusinessURL.Text = "Business URL:";
        // 
        // lblZipCode
        // 
        this.lblZipCode.AutoSize = true;
        this.lblZipCode.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(211, 81);
        this.lblZipCode.Name = "lblZipCode";
        this.lblZipCode.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(53, 13);
        this.lblZipCode.TabIndex = 999;
        this.lblZipCode.Text = "Zip Code:";
        // 
        // lblState
        // 
        this.lblState.AutoSize = true;
        this.lblState.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(147, 81);
        this.lblState.Name = "lblState";
        this.lblState.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(35, 13);
        this.lblState.TabIndex = 999;
        this.lblState.Text = "State:";
        // 
        // lblCity
        // 
        this.lblCity.AutoSize = true;
        this.lblCity.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 81);
        this.lblCity.Name = "lblCity";
        this.lblCity.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(27, 13);
        this.lblCity.TabIndex = 999;
        this.lblCity.Text = "City:";
        // 
        // lblSuite
        // 
        this.lblSuite.AutoSize = true;
        this.lblSuite.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(147, 42);
        this.lblSuite.Name = "lblSuite";
        this.lblSuite.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(34, 13);
        this.lblSuite.TabIndex = 999;
        this.lblSuite.Text = "Suite:";
        // 
        // lblAddress
        // 
        this.lblAddress.AutoSize = true;
        this.lblAddress.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 42);
        this.lblAddress.Name = "lblAddress";
        this.lblAddress.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(48, 13);
        this.lblAddress.TabIndex = 999;
        this.lblAddress.Text = "Address:";
        // 
        // lblBusinessName
        // 
        this.lblBusinessName.AutoSize = true;
        this.lblBusinessName.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 3);
        this.lblBusinessName.Name = "lblBusinessName";
        this.lblBusinessName.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(83, 13);
        this.lblBusinessName.TabIndex = 999;
        this.lblBusinessName.Text = "Business Name:";
        // 
        // pnDates
        // 
        this.pnDates.Controls.Add(this.dtpProjFinish);
        this.pnDates.Controls.Add(this.dtpProjStart);
        this.pnDates.Controls.Add(this.dtpDateDisc);
        this.pnDates.Controls.Add(this.lblProjFinishDate);
        this.pnDates.Controls.Add(this.lblProjStartDate);
        this.pnDates.Controls.Add(this.lblDateDiscovered);
        this.pnDates.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(319, 8);
        this.pnDates.Name = "pnDates";
        this.pnDates.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(232, 124);
        this.pnDates.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // dtpProjFinish
        // 
        this.dtpProjFinish.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(6, 97);
        this.dtpProjFinish.Name = "dtpProjFinish";
        this.dtpProjFinish.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(218, 20);
        this.dtpProjFinish.TabIndex = 15;
        // 
        // dtpProjStart
        // 
        this.dtpProjStart.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(6, 59);
        this.dtpProjStart.Name = "dtpProjStart";
        this.dtpProjStart.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(218, 20);
        this.dtpProjStart.TabIndex = 14;
        // 
        // dtpDateDisc
        // 
        this.dtpDateDisc.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(6, 19);
        this.dtpDateDisc.Name = "dtpDateDisc";
        this.dtpDateDisc.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(218, 20);
        this.dtpDateDisc.TabIndex = 13;
        // 
        // lblProjFinishDate
        // 
        this.lblProjFinishDate.AutoSize = true;
        this.lblProjFinishDate.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 81);
        this.lblProjFinishDate.Name = "lblProjFinishDate";
        this.lblProjFinishDate.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(111, 13);
        this.lblProjFinishDate.TabIndex = 999;
        this.lblProjFinishDate.Text = "Projected Finish Date:";
        // 
        // lblProjStartDate
        // 
        this.lblProjStartDate.AutoSize = true;
        this.lblProjStartDate.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 42);
        this.lblProjStartDate.Name = "lblProjStartDate";
        this.lblProjStartDate.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(106, 13);
        this.lblProjStartDate.TabIndex = 999;
        this.lblProjStartDate.Text = "Projected Start Date:";
        // 
        // lblDateDiscovered
        // 
        this.lblDateDiscovered.AutoSize = true;
        this.lblDateDiscovered.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 3);
        this.lblDateDiscovered.Name = "lblDateDiscovered";
        this.lblDateDiscovered.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(90, 13);
        this.lblDateDiscovered.TabIndex = 999;
        this.lblDateDiscovered.Text = "Date Discovered:";
```

[image]

Comment: Labels can't get focus.  Pick a different control to have the TabIndex = 0 value on.  `this.tbxBusinessName.TabIndex = 0;`

Comment: Did you ever noticed the Tab Order menu in the View menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply put this code in `Load` event of form:

```
this.ActiveControl= this.tbxBusinessName;
```

or

```
this.tbxBusinessName.Select();
```

or

```
this.Visible = true;
this.tbxBusinessName.Focus();
```

All above code will do the trick for you.

**But why** `this.tbxBusinessName.TabIndex = 0;` **didn't work?**

---

Because you have multiple controls with `TabIndex = 0` and in this situations the z-order of controls will check and the control which is on top will win and gain focus first.
For more information you can see [How to: Set the Tab Order on Windows Forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bd16a8cw.aspx).

**And Why simply** `this.tbxBusinessName.Focus();` **Didn't work?**

---

because you can use the `Control.Focus` method in the `Load` event of the form to set the focus on a control only after the `Visible` property of the form is set to true. You can set `this.Visible = true;` or call `this.Show();`

Answer (score 0):

You could manually set the focus by creating an OnLoad function for the window.  Or do as Lars suggested, set the lowest tabIndex on the object you want to have focus.